# Usar Arraylist donde pueda almacenar datos ¿Como vincular Jbutton a cada Objeto del Arraylist de manera induvidual?

Tags: java, java-swing

Veran chicos tengo algunos registros en mi BD los cuales luego creo una Lista de todos estos registros colocandolos en un arraylist mi pregunta es:

Creando una interfaz de usuario con swing , ¿como poder darle un boton individual a cada objeto de ese arraylist ?, ¿Como lo harian ustedes?, Agradecere de muy buena manera todas sus respuestas.

Comment: podrias aclarme tu duda es que no se entiende que quieres hacer

Comment: Quiero hacer un programa que tenga en un jtable todos  los estudiantes de la base de datos y quiero que cada estudiante tenga un boton para enviar información sobre ese estudiante a otra tabla ..

Comment: como un detalle de cada estudiante seria?

Comment: Si, la cuestión es como darle un boton a cada estudiante y ponerle fuente de evento y que cuando presionen el botón envíe la información den estudiante en concreto.

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer no se si lo tienes asi ya que los alumnos sean una clase en base de datos y en java sean un objeto lo tienes asi?